# Unable to create regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I don't have the idea about regex and how to match it with javascript.

I want to validate the string has:-

Min: 0A1

Max: 10J10

```
like: /10|[0-9][A-J]10|[1-10]/
```

But it is not working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What min? What max? What are the rules to govern this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern `[1-10]` matches a range from 1-1 or 0.

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) that matches `[0-9]` (or `[1-9]` for the second case) or `10`:

```
^(?:10|[0-9])[A-J](?:10|[1-9])$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNncpo/2)

```js
let pattern = /^(?:10|[0-9])[A-J](?:10|[1-9])$/;
strings = [
  "0A1",
  "10J10",
  "6A10",
  "11J10"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks @TimPietzcker for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
/([0-9]|10)[A-J]([1-9]|10)/
```

In your regex :

```
[1-10] is wrong : is the same that : any caracters between 1 and 1 or 0
```